# New matrix of mean submatrix - Python

Tags: python, performance, matrix

I have a matrix of [n x m], and I wish to create a new matrix, in which each cell equal to the sum of the 3x3 cells around this cell in the original matrix. The first/last row and column should be equal to the sum of 2x2 cells...
What is the most effective way to do this in Python? (The matrices are awfully large)

Comment: This is called a convolution and there are many previous posts about it and many different ways to do that (including Scipy/Numba/Cython with Numpy). See the ~1400 results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convolution+%5Bnumpy%5D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.ndimage.convolve` for doing this. If all you want is the sum of the elements of each 3x3 window, the kernel will be `np.ones((3,3))`. If you want the average, divide by `9`. Note that the `mode='constant'` option means pad with zeros to compute the sum at the boundaries.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

data = np.arange(0,25).reshape(5,5)

kernel = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
avg_data = ndimage.convolve(data, kernel, mode='constant')
```

For this small example, you get:

```
data
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]

avg_data  
[[ 12  21  27  33  24]
 [ 33  54  63  72  51]
 [ 63  99 108 117  81]
 [ 93 144 153 162 111]
 [ 72 111 117 123  84]]
```